# My Scrapy Crawler don't find nested a href tags

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written a Scrapy crawler as follow:

```
import sys, getopt
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http    import Request
import re

class TutsplusItem(scrapy.Item):
  title = scrapy.Field()

class MySpider(Spider):
  name = "tutsplus"
  allowed_domains   = ["bbc.com"]
  start_urls = ["http://www.bbc.com/"]
  crawling_level=None

  def __init__(self,crawling_level, *args):
      MySpider.crawling_level=crawling_level
      super(MySpider, self).__init__(self)

  def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
    print("Links are %s" %links)
    print ("Crawling level is %s " %MySpider.crawling_level )


    # We stored already crawled links in this list
    level=MySpider.crawling_level
    crawledLinks = []

    # Pattern to check proper link
    # I only want to get the tutorial posts
    # linkPattern = re.compile("^\/tutorials\?page=\d+")


    for link in links:
      # If it is a proper link and is not checked yet, yield it to the Spider
      #if linkPattern.match(link) and not link in crawledLinks:
      if not link in crawledLinks and level>0:
        link = "http://www.bbc.com" + link
        crawledLinks.append(link)
        yield Request(link, self.parse)


    titles = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "media__link")]/@*').extract()
    #titles = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
    print ("Titles are %s" %titles )

    count=0
    for title in titles:
      item = TutsplusItem()
      item["title"] = title
      print("Title is : %s" %title)
      yield item
```

However, there is a problem in my codes and for the line

```
titles = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "media__link")]').extract()
```

it does not return any link. The HTML is as follow:

```
<h3 class="media__title">
  <a class="media__link" href="/news/world-us-canada-38965557" rev="hero1|headline" >
  Trump adviser quits over Russia contacts</a>
</h3>
```

My output titles are always null. Is there anything wrong with my XPATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath in not correct !
use chrome dev tools for xpath debugging:
[image]

```
"//a[@class='media__link']/@href"

titles = response.xpath('//a[@class='media__link']/@href').extract()
```